# Sorry, Parameter is not valid

Tags: c#-2.0

I'm exporting some data to PDF. The data contains one or more bitmaps.
Unfortunately I'm getting the following error during the export.

```
Sorry, Parameter is not valid.
Source:     
   at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Int32 width, Int32 height, PixelFormat format)
   at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Image original, Int32 width, Int32 height)

 Type:    System.ArgumentException
```

Any help will be highly appreciable.

Regards,
Maruthi Kumar

Comment: Does it say *which* parameter isn't valid? And how are you calling this? What arguments are you using?